# NoMethodError: undefined method `spec' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, continuous-deployment

Suddenly I started facing this error after having following gem during deployment on staging server(EngineYard). We use chef recipes for deployment.

**Error log**

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `spec' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  inspect
An error occurred while installing ecwid_api (0.2.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install ecwid_api -v '0.2.2'` succeeds before bundling.
from /home/ey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/engineyard-serverside-2.6.14/lib/engineyard-serverside/servers.rb:85:in `run_on_each!'
```

**Gemfile.lock - Part which looks problematic**

```
GIT
  remote: https://github.com/ParthivPatel-BTC/ecwid_api.git
  revision: 079b697157356612b993e42f1e71269024b7c376
  specs:
    ecwid_api (0.2.2)
      faraday (= 0.12.2)
      faraday_middleware (= 0.10.1)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is it ok to install this gem manual? Can that server connect to github?

Comment: I don't have control as of now as it is being done via chef recipes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with bunlder version

`+    12s     $ ssh -i /home/deploy/.ssh/internal -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/ey-ss-known-hosts20180123-28710-1k6s7ez -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ServerAliveInterval=60 deploy@ec2-54-242-111-22.compute-1.amazonaws.com 'sh -l -c '\''export GIT_SSH="/data/feed_champion/shared/config/feed_champion-ssh-wrapper" && export LANG="en_US.UTF-8" && unset RUBYOPT BUNDLE_PATH BUNDLE_FROZEN BUNDLE_WITHOUT BUNDLE_BIN BUNDLE_GEMFILE && cd /data/feed_champion/releases/20180123225204 && ruby -S bundle _1.7.9_ install --gemfile /data/feed_champion/releases/20180123225204/Gemfile --path /data/feed_champion/shared/bundled_gems --binstubs /data/feed_champion/releases/20180123225204/ey_bundler_binstubs --deployment --without test development'\'`

The Gemfile.lock has `bundler (>= 1.3.0)` as part of `rails` dependency.

All I did to fix is explicitly added `bundler` gem with latest version `1.16.1`